# Web App accessing iOS camera for QR scanning

Tags: ios, html, web-applications, hybrid-mobile-app

For 'check-in' purposes, my staffs have a mobile device (ios and android) that opens my web app through a browser. They then open a page and it allows them to scan a customer's qr code to check them in. I would like it to have as little user interaction as possible. All they staff needs to do is to keep the webapp open, and scan the qr code. The web app will then call an api on my server which check this customer in. So accessing the camera's view is best, i can then run a qr code scanner.

I've been able to do it for android (using getUserMedia) but it doesnt work for ios. (duhhh) 
I'm currently using Vue.js(V1), and would like to keep it as it is. 
Hybrid Apps: I've looked at OnsenUI(which seems to only work with vue2), Ionic(which doesnt allow me to build/run ios platform as i am using windows).

webapp is coded with vue.js(v1), running on a tomcat7 server, HTML, JS.

Are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to use Phonegap to allow this.

Edit: Phonegap allows you to create a hybrid app that seems like a native app(ios or android). All i did was install phonegap and used one of their plugins (barcodescanner). [This](https://www.sitepoint.com/scanning-qr-code-cordova) is the refrence i used.

But, from my understanding, You'll need to publish the app on the app store, which is a lot of hassle (and cost money).